# Unable to get results over a list in a JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jena

I have a problem printing a list in my JSP. Im working with Literal and RDFNode, as im working with RDF.

I have the class Receta:

```
@Table
public class Receta implements Serializable{
@Id
@Column
private Literal nombreReceta;
@Column
private Literal cantidadIngredientes;
@Column
private RDFNode ingredientes;
@Column
private RDFNode modoPreparacion;
@Column
private Literal dificultad;
@Column
private Literal tiempo;
@Column
private Literal calorias;

public Receta(){}

public Receta(Literal nombreReceta, Literal catidadIngredientes, RDFNode ingredientes, RDFNode modoPreparacion, Literal dificultad, Literal tiempo, Literal calorias) {
    this.nombreReceta = nombreReceta;
    this.cantidadIngredientes = catidadIngredientes;
    this.ingredientes = ingredientes;
    this.modoPreparacion = modoPreparacion;
    this.dificultad = dificultad;
    this.tiempo = tiempo;
    this.calorias = calorias;
}

public Literal getNombreReceta() {
    return nombreReceta;
}

public void setNombreReceta(Literal nombreReceta) {
    this.nombreReceta = nombreReceta;
}
```

And so on with getters and setters.

I also have this method:

```
 public static List<Receta> getAllReceipes() {
    List<Receta> list = new ArrayList<>();

    String log4jConfPath = "C:/Users/Karen/workspace/Jena/src/Tutorial/log4j.properties";
    PropertyConfigurator.configure(log4jConfPath);
    try {
        //opening owl file
        Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
        model.read(new FileInputStream("C:/Users/Karen/Desktop/Proyecto/bbdd.owl"), null, "TTL");
        //System.out.println(model);

        //create a new query
        String queryString
                = "PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>"
                + " PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>"
                + " PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>"
                + " PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>"
                + " PREFIX rec:<http://www.receta.org#>"
                + " SELECT ?r ?cal ?tiempo ?dif (COUNT (distinct ?Ingrediente) as ?cantIng) (GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ?modoPreparacion) as ?Preparacion) (GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ?listaIngredientes) as ?listaIng)   "
                + "  WHERE { "
                + "  ?x rdf:type rec:Receta."
                + "  ?x rdfs:label ?r."
                + "  ?x rec:Ingrediente ?Ingrediente."
                + "  ?x rec:modoPreparacion ?modoPreparacion."
                + "  ?x rec:listaIngredientes ?listaIngredientes."
                + "  ?x rec:Calorias ?cal."
                + "  ?x rec:tiempoPreparacion ?tiempo."
                + "  ?x rec:dificultad ?dif."
                + "  } "
                + " GROUP BY ?r ?cal ?tiempo ?dif";

        com.hp.hpl.jena.query.Query q = QueryFactory.create(queryString);
        //execute the query and obtain results
        QueryExecution qe = QueryExecutionFactory.create(q, model);
        ResultSet results = qe.execSelect();

        //print query results
        while (results.hasNext()) {

            QuerySolution qs = results.next();

            Receta rec = new Receta();

            rec.setNombreReceta(qs.getLiteral("r"));
            rec.setCantidadIngredientes(qs.getLiteral("cantIng"));
            rec.setIngredientes(qs.get("listaIng"));
            rec.setModoPreparacion(qs.get("Preparacion"));
            rec.setTiempo(qs.getLiteral("tiempo"));
            rec.setCalorias(qs.getLiteral("cal"));
            rec.setDificultad(qs.getLiteral("dif"));

            list.add(rec);

            System.out.print(rec.getNombreReceta());
        }

    } catch (java.lang.NullPointerException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Query Failed !");
    }
    return list;
}
```

where I get the information that I would like from the data base and save it on a list. 
And I also have the JSP where I would like to show all the values in a table, so I did the following:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="./BuscarRecetaServlet" method="POST">     
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th><FONT FACE="Times New Roman" SIZE=3> NombreReceta </th>
            <th><FONT FACE= "Times New Roman" SIZE=3> CantidadIngredientes     </th>
            <th><FONT FACE= "Times New Roman" SIZE=3> Ingredientes </th>
            <th><FONT FACE= "Times New Roman" SIZE=3> ModoPreparacion </th>
            <th><FONT FACE= "Times New Roman" SIZE=3> Calorias </th>
            <th><FONT FACE= "Times New Roman" SIZE=3> Tiempo </th>
            <th><FONT FACE= "Times New Roman" SIZE=3> Dificultad </th>
        </tr>

  <c:forEach items="${AllReceipes}" var="receipt">        
    <tr>
        <td>name: <c:out value=${receipt.nombreReceta}/></td>
        <td>Cant: <c:out value=${receipt.catidadIngredientes}/></td>
        <td>List: <c:out value=${receipt.ingredientes}/></td>
        <td>Preparation: <c:out value=${receipt.modoPreparacion}/></td>
        <td>Calories: <c:out value=${receipt.calorias}/></td>
        <td>Time: <c:out value=${receipt.tiempo}/></td>
        <td>Dificult: <c:o<ut value=${receipt.dificultad}/></td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
</table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is where I try to print all those values, I just get an empty space:

[image]

I dont know what am I doing wrong. I have this problem since a few days already and I cant find out whats wrong. Any help please?

EDIT: 
     protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        List lIngredients = (List) session.getAttribute("Ingredientes");

```
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    if (lIngredients == null) {
       lIngredients = new ArrayList<>();
       session.setAttribute("Ingredientes", lIngredients);
    }
    String ingrediente = request.getParameter("Ingredientes");
    String cal = request.getParameter("Calorias");
    String tiempoMaximo = request.getParameter("TiempoMax");
    String tiempoMinimo = request.getParameter("TiempoMin");

    String action = request.getParameter("action"); //elegimos a qué pantalla pasar en función de la acción que nos llegue de la interfaz

    if ("Buscar todas las recetas".equalsIgnoreCase(action)) {
        request.setAttribute("AllReceipes", RecetaDao.getAllReceipes());
        request.getRequestDispatcher("receipes.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }else if ("Buscar por ingredientes".equalsIgnoreCase(action)){
              lIngredients.add(ingrediente);
              request.setAttribute("AllIngredients", RecetaDao.getSomeReceipes(lIngredients));
              request.getRequestDispatcher("perIngredient.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }else if ("Agregar ingrediente".equalsIgnoreCase(action)){
             lIngredients.add(ingrediente);
             request.getRequestDispatcher("option.jsp").forward(request, response);
             ingrediente = request.getParameter("Ingredientes");
             action = request.getParameter("action");
    }else if ("Buscar por calorias".equalsIgnoreCase(action)){
                request.setAttribute("AllIngredients", RecetaDao.getReceipesCalories(cal));
                request.getRequestDispatcher("perIngredient.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }else if ("Buscar por tiempo de preparacion".equalsIgnoreCase(action)){
                request.setAttribute("AllReceipes", RecetaDao.getReceipesTime());
                request.getRequestDispatcher("receipes.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }else if ("Buscar por tiempo maximo de preparacion".equalsIgnoreCase(action)){
                request.setAttribute("AllReceipes", RecetaDao.getReceipesMaxTime(tiempoMaximo));
                request.getRequestDispatcher("receipes.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }else if ("Buscar por tiempo minimo de preparacion".equalsIgnoreCase(action)){
                request.setAttribute("AllReceipes", RecetaDao.getReceipesMinTime(tiempoMinimo));
                request.getRequestDispatcher("receipes.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }else if ("Buscar por tiempo acotado de preparacion".equalsIgnoreCase(action)){
                request.setAttribute("AllReceipes", RecetaDao.getReceipesBetweenMinMax(tiempoMinimo, tiempoMaximo));
                request.getRequestDispatcher("receipes.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }else if ("Buscar recetas por dificultad".equalsIgnoreCase(action)){
                request.setAttribute("AllReceipes", RecetaDao.getReceipesDifficulty());
                request.getRequestDispatcher("receipes.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }else if ("Buscar recetas de dificultad baja y media".equalsIgnoreCase(action)){
                request.setAttribute("AllReceipes", RecetaDao.getReceipesEasyMediumDif());
                request.getRequestDispatcher("receipes.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }else if ("Buscar recetas de dificultad media y alta".equalsIgnoreCase(action)){
                request.setAttribute("AllReceipes", RecetaDao.getReceipesMediumHardDif());
                request.getRequestDispatcher("receipes.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

Comment: Dont you need to use quotes like                                                             <c:out value="${receipt.nombreReceta}/>"

Comment: No, I don´t need. I just need the value inside receipt.nombreReceta

Comment: `<td>Dificult: <c:o<ut value=${receipt.dificultad}/></td>` this line is wrong. It should be `<td>Dificult: <c:out value=${receipt.dificultad}/></td>`

Comment: Thanks for the point, I already changed it, but I still have empty boxes. still not have the value inside receipt.dificultad (or others)

Comment: Also `${receipt.catidadIngredientes}` isn't matching ur member variable `cantidadIngredientes`.

Comment: Does this solves ur problem ? Did u get data in table ?

Comment: I changed it but it still the same

Comment: `items="${allReceipes}"` with a smal `a`?

Comment: No.. The name on the servlet is AllReceipes, with capital letter. Anyway I tried and nothing..

Comment: Can u show the code, how did u tried to add this list in JSP from servlet & in which scope ?

Comment: When I do <td>${AllReceipes}</td> then I get all the information, but on the same box. The problem is when I try to get each element on the forEach

Comment: Have u added JSLT **CORE tag library** in JSP page ? It's not in your JSP code. If not then add `<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>` & try to run with for-each loop.

Comment: OMG I havent... It was such as stupid as this. THANKS!! Post an answer so I can rate you, thanks

Comment: No problem. I'll post answer in few minutes. It happens sometimes when we are in hurry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Few things you missed in your code:

**The most important JSTL tag library:**

```
Add <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%> in your JSP.
```

**Mis-spelled member variable:**

```
<td>Cant: <c:out value=${receipt.catidadIngredientes}/></td>
isn't matching ur member variable cantidadIngredientes

@Column
private Literal cantidadIngredientes;
```